# How to disable scaling for radio input?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

So there is a radio input:

`<input style="width: 10px; height: 10px;" type="radio" />`

The problem is when i change the zoom in Firefox, the radio input stays with the same size - scales to the screen -.

What am I missing?

Comment: radio buttons wont scale up.

Comment: Probably have more luck wrapping it in/putting it before a label and styling that label instead.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I'm not very good with html and css, so can you please tell me briefly what should i do using a short piece of code?

Comment: The concept is fairly simple.  It relies on adjacent sibling selectors and the CSS3 `:checked` selector.  You create a label right after the input so that you can style the unchecked state with `input + label` and the checked state with `input:checked + label`.  Using `for` and `id`, you can make it such that clicking on the label checks or unchecks the input.  Then you just hide the input.  It's a nice little way to style radios and checkboxes without the hassle of dealing with browser styles.  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sp39w0t8/